Erro de TypeError: obj.Quill is not a constructor
Estoy teniendo un error que llevo días sin saber como solucionarlo.
Estoy usando nextJs para este proyecto y la librería npm react-quilljs versión: "^1.3.3"
Tengo el código en el archivo: quienes_somos.tsx
import { Col, Row, Form, Card, Button, Image, Table, Modal, Accordion, Placeholder } from "react-bootstrap";
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useQuill } from 'react-quilljs';
import toolbar from '@/config/toolbar'
import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css'

const QuienesSomos = () => {
    const [datos, setDatos] = useState([] as any);
    const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState('');
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const [banners, setBanners] = useState('');
    const [insertText, setInsertText] = useState('');
    const [recurso1, setRecurso1] = useState('');
    const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState();
    const [buttonEnabled, setButtonEnabled] = useState(false);
    const { quill, quillRef } = useQuill({
        modules: {
            toolbar: toolbar,
        },
    });

    const handleChange = (e:any) => {
        const { id, value } = e.target;
        switch (id) {
            case 'id':
                setSelectedId(value);
                break;
            case 'recurso1':
                setRecurso1(value);
                break;
            case 'categoria':
                setCategoria(value);
                break;
            default:
                setTitle(value);
                break;
        }
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        const verificador = window.location.pathname.split('/');
        const rptAPI = verificador[verificador.length - 1];

        fetch('/json/api.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                const data: any[] = json.pginformacion;
                let filtrado: any[] = data.filter((fila: any) => fila.categoria === rptAPI);
                setDatos(filtrado);
                setBanners(rptAPI);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Tenemos un error', error));
    }, []);

    const handleLinkClick = (id:any, content:any, recurso1:any, categoria:any, title:any) => {
        setButtonEnabled(!false);
        setRecurso1(recurso1);
        setInsertText(content);
        setCategoria(categoria);
        setTitle(title);
        setSelectedId(id);
        if (quill) {
            quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(content);
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = async () => {

        try {
            let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/pginformacion';
            let method = 'POST';
            if (selectedId) {
                apiUrl += `/${selectedId}`;
                method = 'PUT';
            }

            const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
                method: method,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    id: selectedId,
                    title: title,
                    content: quill.root.innerHTML,
                    categoria: 'empresa',
                    recurso1: recurso1,

                }),
            });
            //   console.log('Respuesta del servidor recibida:', response);
            // Aquí agregamos los console.log adicionales
            response.json().then(data => {
                console.log('Datos de la respuesta:', data);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error('Error al convertir la respuesta a JSON:', error);
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                console.log(`Información ${selectedId ? 'actualizada' : 'guardada'} con éxito.`);
                fetch('http://localhost:3001/pginformacion')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => setDatos(data))

                    .catch(error => console.error('Error al obtener datos:', error));
            } else {
                console.error(`Error al ${selectedId ? 'actualizar' : 'guardar'} la información.`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error de red:', error);
        }
    };


    // const procesarContenidoQuill = (contenidoQuill) => {
    //     return contenidoQuill;
    // };

    const handleDeleteClick = (id:any) => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/pginformacion/${id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    fetch('http://localhost:3001/pginformacion')
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => setDatos(data))
                        .catch(error => console.error('Error al obtener datos:', error));
                } else {
                    console.error('Error al eliminar el registro.');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error de red:', error);
            });
    };

    const confirmDelete = (id:any) => {
        const shouldDelete = window.confirm("¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar este registro?");

        if (shouldDelete) {
            handleDeleteClick(id);
        }
    };

    const handleCleanClick = () => {
        setRecurso1('');
        setInsertText("");
        setTitle("");
        setCategoria(null as any);
        if (quill) {
            quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(content);
        }
        setButtonEnabled(false)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Row className="col-12 col-lg-6 mt-5">
                <Col xl={12} lg={12} md={12} xs={12}>
                    {datos.map((fila:any, index:any) => (
                        <Card className='mb-3' key={index}>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <div className='row'>
                                    <Row className="mb-1 align-items-center justify-content-end">
                                        <div className="col-auto">
                                            <button type="button" className='bg-white fa-lg text-primary border-0 rounded-3' onClick={() => handleLinkClick(fila.id, fila.content, fila.recurso1, fila.recurso2, fila.categoria)} ><i className='fe fe-edit fa-md'></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </Row>
                                    <hr />
                                    <Row>
                                        <div className='col-md-12 col-12'>
                                            {fila.content && (
                                                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: fila.content }} />
                                            )}
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='col-md-12 col-12'>
                                            <div className='row'>
                                                <div className="container">
                                                    <form >
                                                        <Row className="mb-1">
                                                            <div className="col-md-12 col-12">
                                                                <Image src={fila.recurso1} className='img-thumbnail rounded-4' alt='Text' />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </Row>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </Row>
                                </div>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    ))}

                </Col>
            </Row>

            <Row className='col-12 col-lg-6  mb-8 mt-3'>
                <Col xl={12} lg={12} md={12} xs={12}>
                    <Card>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <div className='row'>
                                <div className="container">
                                    <form>
                                        <Row className="mb-1">
                                            <div className="col-md-12 col-12">
                                                <label htmlFor='title'>Identificador Único:</label>
                                                <input type='text' placeholder="Ejm: 1" disabled className='p-2 border-0 text-muted ms-2 mb-2 border-bottom border border-primary' id='id' value={selectedId} onChange={handleChange} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'black' }}></input>
                                            </div>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row className="mb-3">
                                            <div className="col-md-12 col-12">
                                                <input type='text' placeholder='Título' disabled className='p-2 bg-secondary text-light accordion-button rounded-2' id='value' value={title} onChange={handleChange}></input>
                                            </div>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row className="mb-3">
                                            <div className="col-md-12 col-12">
                                                <div className='editor'>
                                                    <div ref={quillRef}></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row className="mb-3">
                                            <div className="col-12 ">
                                                <label htmlFor='recurso1'>Imagen o Video:</label>
                                                <input
                                                    type='text'
                                                    placeholder='para la 1 columna'
                                                    className='form-control mt-2'
                                                    id='recurso1' value={recurso1}
                                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                                />
                                            </div>

                                        </Row>
                                        <Row className="mb-3">
                                            <div className="col-md-12 col-12 text-end">
                                                <Button className='btn btn-secondary' 
                                                    type='reset' 
                                                    onClick={() => handleCleanClick()} 
                                                    disabled={!buttonEnabled}
                                                >Limpiar</Button>
                                                <Button className='btn btn-success m-1' 
                                                    type='submit' 
                                                    onClick={() => handleSubmit()} 
                                                    disabled={!buttonEnabled}
                                                >Guardar</Button>
                                            </div>
                                        </Row>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    )

}

export default QuienesSomos

En el visual, me indica que este parte del codigo mostrado anteriormente, hay un error
 body: JSON.stringify({
      id: selectedId,
      title: title,
      content: quill.root.innerHTML,
      categoria: 'empresa',
      recurso1: recurso1,

 }),


'quill' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)

Archivo: package.json
{
  "name": "procasanortetmp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.1",
    "bootswatch": "^5.3.2",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "quickmenu": "^1.4.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.10",
    "react-quilljs": "^1.3.3",
    "react-responsive": "^10.0.0",
    "router": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "sass": "^1.72.0",
    "simplebar": "^6.2.5",
    "simplebar-react": "^3.2.4",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "svg": "^0.1.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.10.7",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

Al correr el comando npm run dev, corre normal se levanta. El problema ocurre cuando ingreso a la ruta de ese archivo desde la web y me lanza este error.

1 of 1 unhandled error Next.js (14.1.0) out of date (learn more)
Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: obj.Quill is not a constructor
Call Stack eval node_modules\react-quilljs\esm\index.js (80:24) create
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(21035:22) commitHookEffectListMount
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23088:6) commitHookPassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23193:10) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23268:12) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23304:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23304:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23304:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23304:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23304:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23304:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23304:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23304:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23268:12) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23304:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23304:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8) commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23171:6) recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js
(23190:8)
Espero por favor me puedan ayudar. Gracias..


parece que quill no esta ... XD

También instale anteriormente y el error persistía
